# How to change page view dynamically in angular2?

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular2 and I get a problem right now. In my page, I have a "Log in" button. After user logged in, I want to change it to "Log out". Since this button is in app.component, it gets loaded only once. Thanks in advance.

---

My app.component.html

```
<a *ngIf="signedIn==true" [routerLink]="['Logout']">Log out</a>
<a *ngIf="signedIn==false" [routerLink]="['Login']">Log in</a>
```

App.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private _loginService: LoginService) {}
   signedIn: boolean = this._loginService.isSignedIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since RxJS is bundled in with Angular2 the approach I like would be to remodel the `isSignedIn` member as an Observable and subscribe to it. Example in [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WBj7mQW6dJcfAqas1Zu0).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should leverage a shared service for this since you're using routing and this involves several components.

If you want to share a state / property between them, you need to add it into your service along with an observable / subject to notify other components when the state changes.

Here is a sample:

```
export class LoginService {
  isSignedIn: boolean;
  isSignedInSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  setSignedIn() {
    this.isSignedIn = true;
    this.isSignedInSubject.next(true);
  }

  setSignedOut() {
    this.isSignedIn = false;
    this.isSignedInSubject.next(false);
  }
}
```

The main component can subscribe on the subject to be notified when the signedIn state changes.

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <a *ngIf="signedIn==true" [routerLink]="['Logout']">Log out</a>
    <a *ngIf="signedIn==false" [routerLink]="['Login']">Log in</a>      
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _loginService:LoginService) {
    this._loginService.isSignedInSubject.subscribe(isSignedIn => {
      this.signedIn = isSignedIn;
    });
  }
}
```

For more details, you could haver a look at this question:

- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924)